# Implicit Conversion of Templated Class for Operator==()

Tags: c++, templates, operator-keyword, implicit-conversion

I have a templated class like so:

```
struct Base
{
    bool operator==(const Base& other) const {
        return v == other.v;
    }
    int v;
};
struct Abc : public Base
{
    void execute() { /*logic1*/ }
};

struct Def : public Base
{
    void execute() { /*logic2*/ }
};

template <typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    bool operator==(const Foo& other) const {
        return (a == other.a) && (b == other.b);
    }

    int a;
    T b;
};
```

This works fine, however I'd like to extend this operator==() method to allow the equality to only be valid if the object passed in is of the same templated type. Here's an example:

```
Foo<Abc> obj1;
Foo<Abc> obj2;
Foo<Def> obj3;

obj1 == obj2; // should be true
obj1 == obj3; // should fail at compile-time or run-time
```

When I do this:

```
bool operator==(const Foo& other) const {
    std::cerr << typeid(other).name() << std::endl;
    return (a == other.a) && (b == other.b);
}
```

I notice that the instance of the class passed in is implicitly converted into the type of this class. I thought about including a member variable on the templated object to distinguish them, but it's a little annoying to have to add an extra variable it feels like I shouldn't need. Is there a better way of achieving this equality test?

Comment: Your operator can only accept `Foo<T>` or a derived class. Have you derived from Foo, does it have implicit constructors? What is the problem.

Comment: "to allow the equality to only be valid if the object passed in is of the same templated type". What other types are currently allowed that you don't want?

Comment: @NeilKirk - no derived classes from Foo. At the moment operator==() works for different T types through implicit conversion. I seem to only have the choice to remove the operator==() entirely (to prevent implicit conversion), or leave it in and get implicit conversion. I want to be able to compare two objects such as Foo<T1> and Foo<T1> and fail to compare Foo<T1> and Foo<T2> either at compile-time or run-time.

Comment: @n.m. - It currently allows any other types for T that have the same member variables, I wish to disallow this as the functionality is different. See my reply above for more context.

Comment: Can you provide an example of calling the operator that you want to disallow?

Comment: Posted code doesn't match your claim. Show an example where you compare `Foo<int>` and `Foo<double>` and the compiler allows it.

Comment: @NeilKirk - Updated with an example. Sorry for the ambiguity, hopefully that's clearer.

Comment: @n.m. - Extended with a bit more explanation.

Comment: It does fail at compile-time: http://ideone.com/1xKkIY

Comment: Your edited code is substantially different from the original. It now has a base class with its own `operator==`. This could be a problem with either object slicing or derived-to-base pointer or reference conversion. Your posted code does not exhibit this problem but perhaps your real code does. I recommend removing `operator==()` from `Base` and making `Base` an abstract class.

Comment: The code you have posted [already fails for the marked line](http://ideone.com/ThO5YE)

Comment: Apologies, I was attempting to ask a simplified version of the problem I was facing, but rather over-simplified this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, there exists implicit conversion from `Foo<T1>` to `Foo<T2>`.

Possible solutions are:

1. Forbid implicit type conversion (use `explicit` keyword for constructors and cast operators).
2. Make `operator ==` templated and use `enable_if` to allow only possible combinations:

   ```
   template <typename T1, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, T2>::value>::type>
   bool operator == (const Foo<T1>& other) const
   ```

Comment: Thanks, the second option looks viable. Can you give an example of how the first option would help for this use case?

Comment: Just provide some more code as requested in the comments.